# How to add keys and values from two dictionaries to third without mixing between them?

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries and I want to add their content to third dictionary naturally without mixing their between them.

```
a = {'life':'1','arts':'2'}
b = {'technology':'3', 'culture':'4'}
c = {} # here must be keys and values of the `a` and `b` dicts
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without mixing between them"?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

Comment: `c.update(a); c.update(b)` This is inplace and returns `None` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try to use **zip** keyword

```
a = {'life':'1','arts':'2'}
b = {'technology':'3', 'culture':'4'}
for q, s in zip(a, b):
    print(q, a[q])
    print(s, b[s])
```